# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider with factories in multiple files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple files with some factories in it. The files are getting packet into one file, when the project is builded.

And on execution I get the error

```
angularAndPlugins.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: settingsProvider <- settings

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=settingsProvider%20%3C-%20settings
```

The Project is a bit bigger and got the following structure:

```
~/
 app.js
 index.html

~/app/factories/
 siHistory.factory.js
 siPopup.factory.js

~/app/directives/...
~/app/filters/...
~/app/modules/...
```

All the files in the factories-directory contains

```
/// <reference path="~/src/References.js" />

angular.module('supream').factory('$siHistory', [function () {
   'use strict';
   /// Some code
}];
```

I am out of ideas and any help will be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well the error is very clear: in angularAndPlugins.js you are trying to inject inexistent service named `settings`.

Comment: i am such a fool. thank you very much :D

Comment: i tought the word settings is part of the error-name :S